# How / where to save persistent data using VBA in MS Project 2003

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm currently writing a macro using the MS Project 2003 Visual Basic editor, for which I need to save a path to an template excel spreadsheet.  I'd like the user to be able to change the path and for the setting to be persistently saved somewhere.

Is there a convenient location to save persistent data using VBA for MS Project 2003?  I was thinking perhaps in a custom field of Global.mpt, but I'm not sure how to access it.

Comment: The macro is currently contained in a module stored in Global.mpt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA has two built-in functions `GetSetting` and `SaveSetting` that allow you to simply and safely save persistent string data to the registry.  The data is saved in a folder off of the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive, so the data is saved by user, not by machine.

See here for details:  [Use the GetSetting and SaveSetting Functions to Read and Write Registry Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164019%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_tentipsvba_topic8)

Answer (score 1):

Using Registry to store persistent data will not work if the file is used in another system.
You could use the `CustomDocumentProperties` to store any value you want and it'll be stored along with the file.